# How to use DevForce2010 with JSON-service?

Tags: json, silverlight-4.0, devforce

I use Silverlight and DevForce 2010.
My entity manager has a standard setup with a database at the server.

Now I want my Silverlight client to talk to a JSON-service and make the data-results into entities. These entities must not be saved to the back-end database server (as the other entities).

What is the right way to do this?

Do I use PocoServiceProvider and PocoSaveAdapter, and can these be setup to only exist on the client?

I was thinking of using WebClient to talk to the JSON-service and use DataContractJsonSerializer to convert results into entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevForce itself does not understand JSON or REST so can't directly be used.  If you want to use the entities within an EntityManager and give the appearance of db-backed entities, then the POCO approach should work.

Comment: I made a workable solution with WebClient, DataContractJsonSerializer and the DevForce POCO approach.